# Python self and super in multiple inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, self, super, method-resolution-order

In Raymond Hettinger's talk "[Super considered super speak](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo)" at PyCon 2015 he explains the advantages of using `super` in Python in multiple inheritance context. This is one of the examples that Raymond used during his talk:

```
class DoughFactory(object):
    def get_dough(self):
        return 'insecticide treated wheat dough'


class Pizza(DoughFactory):
    def order_pizza(self, *toppings):
        print('Getting dough')
        dough = super().get_dough()
        print('Making pie with %s' % dough)
        for topping in toppings:
            print('Adding: %s' % topping)


class OrganicDoughFactory(DoughFactory):
    def get_dough(self):
        return 'pure untreated wheat dough'


class OrganicPizza(Pizza, OrganicDoughFactory):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    OrganicPizza().order_pizza('Sausage', 'Mushroom')
```

Somebody in the audience [asked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo&t=41m10s) Raymond about the difference of using `self.get_dough()` instead `super().get_dough()`. I didn't understand very well the brief answer of Raymond but I coded the two implementations of this example to see the differences. The output are the same for both cases:

```
Getting dough
Making pie with pure untreated wheat dough
Adding: Sausage
Adding: Mushroom
```

If you alter the class order from `OrganicPizza(Pizza, OrganicDoughFactory)` to `OrganicPizza(OrganicDoughFactory, Pizza)` using `self.get_dough()`, you will get this result:

`Making pie with pure untreated wheat dough`

However if you use `super().get_dough()` this is the output:

`Making pie with insecticide treated wheat dough`

I understand the `super()` behavior as Raymond explained. But what is the expected behavior of `self` in multiple inheritance scenario?

Comment: what the - pizza inherits from a *dough factory*? This code is weird.

Comment: `self` behaves exactly like any other reference to the object. If you do `p = OrganicPizza()`, then `self.get_dough()` in any method of `p` is equivalent to `p.get_dough()`, no matter where in the inheritance graph the use of `self` occurs. Do you understand what `p.get_dough()` would do?

Comment: @user2357112 why is weird? Is only a simple example that Raymond proposed in his talk.

Comment: @MarcTudurí I think they mean from a real-world object modelling perspective - it would make more sense to call it `Pizzeria`/`OrganicPizzeria` (and the `DoughFactory` is still a *"mix-in"*!)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just to clarify, there are four cases, based on changing the second line in `Pizza.order_pizza` and the definition of `OrganicPizza`:

1. `super()`, `(Pizza, OrganicDoughFactory)` *(original)*: `'Making pie with pure untreated wheat dough'`
2. `self`, `(Pizza, OrganicDoughFactory)`: `'Making pie with pure untreated wheat dough'`
3. `super()`, `(OrganicDoughFactory, Pizza)`: `'Making pie with insecticide treated wheat dough'`
4. `self`, `(OrganicDoughFactory, Pizza)`: `'Making pie with pure untreated wheat dough'`

Case 3. is the one that's surprised you; if we switch the order of inheritance but still use `super`, we apparently end up calling the original `DoughFactory.get_dough`.

---

What `super` really does is ask *"which is next in the MRO (method resolution order)?"* So what does `OrganicPizza.mro()` look like?

- `(Pizza, OrganicDoughFactory)`: `[<class '__main__.OrganicPizza'>, <class '__main__.Pizza'>, <class '__main__.OrganicDoughFactory'>, <class '__main__.DoughFactory'>, <class 'object'>]`
- `(OrganicDoughFactory, Pizza)`: `[<class '__main__.OrganicPizza'>, <class '__main__.OrganicDoughFactory'>, <class '__main__.Pizza'>, <class '__main__.DoughFactory'>, <class 'object'>]`

The crucial question here is: which comes *after* `Pizza`? As we're calling `super` from inside `Pizza`, that is where Python will go to find `get_dough`*. For 1. and 2. it's `OrganicDoughFactory`, so we get the pure, untreated dough, but for 3. and 4. it's the original, insecticide-treated `DoughFactory`.

---

Why is `self` different, then? `self` is always *the instance*, so Python goes looking for `get_dough` from the start of the MRO. In both cases, as shown above, `OrganicDoughFactory` is earlier in the list than `DoughFactory`, which is why the `self` versions *always* get untreated dough; `self.get_dough` always resolves to `OrganicDoughFactory.get_dough(self)`.

---

* *I think that this is actually clearer in the two-argument form of `super` used in Python 2.x, which would be `super(Pizza, self).get_dough()`; the first argument is the class to skip (i.e. Python looks in the rest of the MRO after that class).*

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to share a few observations on this.

Calling `self.get_dough()` may be not possible if you are overriding the `get_dough()` method of the parent class, like here:

```
class AbdullahStore(DoughFactory):
    def get_dough(self):
        return 'Abdullah`s special ' + super().get_dough()
```

I think this is a frequent scenario in practice. If we call `DoughFactory.get_dough(self)` directly then the behaviour is fixed. A class deriving `AbdullahStore` would have to override
the complete method and cannot reuse the 'added value' of `AbdullahStore`. On the other hand, if we use `super.get_dough(self)`, this has a flavour of a template:
in any class derived from `AbdullahStore`, say

```
class Kebab(AbdullahStore):
    def order_kebab(self, sauce):
        dough = self.get_dough()
        print('Making kebab with %s and %s sauce' % (dough, sauce))
```

we can 'instantiate' `get_dough()` used in `AbdullahStore` differently, by intercepting it in MRO like this

```
class OrganicKebab(Kebab, OrganicDoughFactory):pass
```

Here's what it does:

```
Kebab().order_kebab('spicy')
Making kebab with Abdullah`s special insecticide treated wheat dough and spicy sauce
OrganicKebab().order_kebab('spicy')
Making kebab with Abdullah`s special pure untreated wheat dough and spicy sauce
```

Since `OrganicDoughFactory` has a single parent `DoughFactory`, I it is guaranteed to be inserted in MRO right before `DoughFactory` and thus overrides its methods for all the preceding classes in MRO. It took me some time to understand the C3 linearization algorithm used to construct the MRO.
The problem is that the two rules

```
children come before parents
parents order is preserved
```

from this reference https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ do not yet define the ordering unambiguously. In the class hierarchy

```
D->C->B->A
 \      /
   --E--
```

(class A; class B(A); class C(B); class E(A); class D(C,E)) where E will be inserted in MRO? Is it DCBEA or DCEBA? Perhaps before one can confidently answer questions like this, it is not such a good idea to start inserting `super` everywhere. I am still not completely sure, but I think C3 linearization, which *is* unambiguous and will choose the ordering DCBEA in this example, does
allow us to do the interception trick the way we did it, unambiguously.

Now, I suppose you can predict the result of

```
class KebabNPizza(Kebab, OrganicPizza): pass
KebabNPizza().order_kebab('hot')
```

which is an improved kebab:

```
Making kebab with Abdullah`s special pure untreated wheat dough and hot sauce
```

But it has probably taken you some time to calculate.

When I first looked at the `super` docs https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super a weak ago, coming from C++ background, it was like "wow, ok here are the rules, but how this can ever work and not stub you in the back?".
Now I understand more about it, but still reluctant from inserting `super` everywhere. I think most of the codebase I have seen is doing it just because `super()` is more convenient to type than the base class name.
And this is even not speaking about the extreme use of `super()` in chaining the `__init__` functions. What I observe in practice is that everybody write constructors with the signature that is convenient for the class (and not the universal one) and use `super()` to call what they think is their base class constructor.